# Underfind index in session

Tags: php, session

I try to load a session as I want with me into my handler. But the line 8 says that "during the find index" what is the error in my controller? It is a user name that I want to use a database to retrieve the id of the person.
Controller:

```
 <?php
 require_once ("View/PersonInfoView.php");
 require_once ("Handler/UserHandler.php");
 class PersonInfoController{
public function DoPersonInfo(){
    $Personinfoview = new PersonInfoView();
    $UserHandler = new UserHandler();
    $PK = $UserHandler->GetUserID($_SESSION['Person']);
    $Person_array = $UserHandler->ListPerson($PK);

    $Personinfoview->Personbox($Person_array);

}

 }
```

I set Session :

```
     <?php
   require_once ("Handler/Userhandler.php");
  require_once ("Controller/LoginController.php");
 class DologinHandler{  
public function Login(){ 

if(isset($_REQUEST['is_ajax']))
    {
        $LoginController = new LoginController();
        $username = $_REQUEST['username'];
        $password = $_REQUEST['password'];
        $_SESSION['Person'] = $username;
        $UserHandler = new UserHandler();
        $sign = $UserHandler -> controllDB($username,$password);

        if($sign == true)
        {
            echo 'success'; 
            return true;    
        }
        else 
        {
            echo 'error';
            return false;
        }
       }
      }

 }
     $loginclass = new DologinHandler();
     $loginclass->Login();
```

Comment: Any specific line of error stated?

Comment: @dqlopez "Rad eight" is probably line 8.

Comment: Also, if you get an error message, please do update your question with that whole exact error message.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing your `$_REQUEST` doesn't contain the key `Person`. Try doing a `var_dump()` on `$_REQUEST` to see what it contains.

Other than that, I suggest you implement some kind of error handeling when calling `$UserHandler->GetUserID()`

For instance.

```
try {
    $PK = $UserHandler->GetUserID($_SESSION['Person']);
} catch(Exception $e) {
    echo($e->getMessage());
}
```

[Read about exceptions](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php).

Comment: So my assumptions were right. `$_REQUEST['username']` doesn't contain anything.

Comment: but I session_start in my index.php a set in my stack.php and get it in my controller. what wrong?

Comment: I can't tell you what the problem is without seeing the rest of your code, and to be honest, it's outside the scope of above question. Although it doesn't solve your problem entirely my answer is correct and should point you in the right direction on where to search for the error. A hint would be to check where you set the `username` key in `$_REQUEST`

Comment: Line 10 in the second .php file (I don't know the name) states: `$username = $_REQUEST['username'];`. Where does `$_REQUEST` come from? Because it doesn't contain any value for the key `username`.